# Applications in Ubuntu's installation environment

Tags: installation, custom-installer

For installation, a Linux session is loaded to the memory, so my questions are:

- What applications are executed during this session?
- How can I add more applications to use?

Related to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29632/guide-to-particulars-in-preseeding-ubuntu-installer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a custom livecd easily with UCK. http://uck.sourceforge.net/

I've done it several times for different needs and it works perfectly.

Comment: I know about UCK, but when going into a live session, does it only have the packages I specified or is it only for installation?

Comment: The changes you make with Synaptic are reflected in both the live environmente and the installed system. In fact the Ubiquity installer copies the filesystem of the livecd and makes only a few changes (in the sources.list sometimes). So if you made a livecd with e.g. Audacity preinstalled, you can use it to install Ubuntu and get Audacity by default (+ all the other Ubuntu defaults if you don't remove them). Note that if you grow the ISO a lot in the installer you'll see something strange like "copying files... 246% completed". Don't worry, it's ok.