# Preseed file being ignored during installation

Tags: installation, preseed, custom-installer

I've followed this document pretty well ([Guide to particulars in customizing Ubuntu Installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29121/guide-to-particulars-in-customizing-ubuntu-installer) / specifically: https://askubuntu.com/a/29632/36927), however it seems to ignore the preseed.cfg file I created.  I've included this in initrd when it is rebuilt (following the directions) and I also tried appending it as a boot option (/cdrom/preseed.cfg), either way the options in the preseed.cfg file aren't being used.  I've tested by by having a late_command wget a file from my server, and also by throwing a text file on the target / filesystem.

I'm really hoping that I'm missing something simple...but so far I can't seem to figure out what it would be.

Thanks

Comment: Building a custom iso is a complex task. Please describe what you are trying to do exactly (just a "simple" preseed, or are you running commands ? ) and pastebin the relevant files (preseed, initrd).

Comment: I literally cut and pasted these steps:

http://askubuntu.com/a/29632

My preseed file is from the example (https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt), save as preseed.cfg.  I uncommented the last preseed/late_command:

d-i preseed/late_command string apt-install zsh; in-target chsh -s /bin/zsh

Then I built the CD:

http://pastie.org/2978235

Comment: What is not working ? Just the failure of apt to install zsh ?

Comment: How are you building this custom iso ? If you are not using them, I highly advise the debian live scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The only obvious thing I see is with your apt command. It should read

```
apt-get install zsh
```

I am not sure about the rest of the command either.

```
apt-get install zsh; chsh ubuntu -s /bin/zsh
```

Comment: I've tried apt-get install zsh, and I've also tried using wget to pull a file from my server to see if that works.  Either way, nothing is pulled from my server and zsh isn't installed.

Comment: How are you customizing the iso ? IMO you are best off using the debian live scripts, and in that case you simply add zsh to the package list. I personally wrote a custom boot script to touch up what I could not with the build scripts, I think changing the default shell to zsh was one of the tasks.

Comment: Hrm, I'll look into it.  Do you happen to have any links that I can look at on using debian live scripts to build a Ubuntu install CD?

Comment: http://live.debian.net/manual/html/live-manual.en.html  Those instructions work on ubuntu as well. The ubuntu man page also helps http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man7/live-helper.7.html You sort of need to slowly work through the first page I gave you, yes it takes a little time to learn, but the result is quite nice.